# Bookmarklet dropdown with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I need some js to build a bookmarklet in order to complete a form.
Here goes the HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
    <td>
      <div class="select2-container select2-container-active" id="s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1"> 
            <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">Select an Option</span> 
                <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> 
                    <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"> <b role="presentation"></b></span></a>
                        <label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label> 
                            <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2" tabindex="0" autocomplete="Female">
      </div>
      <select name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:personDetails:genderDropDownList" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList" onchange="nzis.UpdateDropdownErrorLabel(this)" errorlabel="mandatory" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;">
         <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
         <option value="M">Male</option>
         <option value="F">Female</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I tried with some JS without success.
JS:

```
var index = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').selectedIndex;
    alert("value="+document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').value);
    alert("text="+document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').options[1].text);
s2id_autogen2.value= document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').options[2].text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the bookmarklet like this:

```
javascript: (function() {
    var eltSelect = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList');
    eltSelect.options[2].selected = true;
    eltSelect.onchange();
    s2id_autogen2.value = eltSelect.options[eltSelect.selectedIndex].text;
})();
```

Comment: Just tested it and I think it's close. 
Here is an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qn7atLL/


The code you game me selected the option automatically. I just need to get it on the "Select an option" box now.
The HTML in the jsfiddle is the same I wrote in my question with one different thing. I removed the dropdown style  "display: none" so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I updated the bookmarklet by adding one additional line of code.

Comment: You are a GENIOUS!!! It worked :D
I have one more question. How can I add multiple ID's to this code?
I mean I have:
'ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList'
'ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderTitleDownList'
'ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderCountryDownList'

And so many more..

I think maybe making more "eltSelect" functions.

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, your idea is correct. Just add new lines in the bookmarklet function.